# Is it possible to intercept Java 11 HttpClient requests?

Tags: java, http, interceptor, java-http-client

Basically as the title says. Apache HttpClient and Spring RestTemplate allow for defining custom interceptors which wrap around requests/responses and allow for additional (global) modification of request parameters, logging, etc...

I do not see such a feature available in standard Java implementation of `java.net.http.HttpClient` (as of Java 11). Am I missing something or is there no way to intercept all requests/responses on a single `HttpClient`?

Comment: It seems like you can accomplish each of those things with one or two lines of code.  Are you just looking for a Spring-like way to do them?

Comment: @VGR one or two additional lines of code for each request? The only way I currently imagine I could modify/log all requests/responses of a `HttpClient` without duplicating code is to wrap `HttpClient` into a custom class and implement interceptors around all `send` calls myself. If I'm missing something obvious please let me know.

Comment: If you want a special “global” method that is magically called whenever any instance of HttpClient executes, you want a Spring-like way of doing it.  Otherwise, you’re correct;  you log each usage of an HttpClient instance, just as you would do when using an instance of any other Java SE class.  If you have a great many HttpClient calls, making a wrapper class isn’t a bad idea.

Comment: I think it is pretty sad that nowadays such absolutely useful features don't make their way into Java SE. Maybe I want to create a little app that fetches data from a REST endpoint without adding a full-blown Spring, CDI (or whatever EE) environment. And yes - there are client libs for REST calls but why shouldn't Java SE be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a built-in solution, but you can write your own code as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455589) or use this [interceptable-http-client](https://github.com/raphw/interceptable-http-client) library.