# Logging in JDK11 HttpClient

Tags: java, http, logging, java-11, java-http-client

JDK11 introduced a new HTTP Client, with many features that lacks in traditional `java.net.HttpURLConnection` class. First question that I encountered with is how to properly enable logging in newly added HTTP Client?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215038/how-to-log-request-response-using-java-net-http-httpclient/53231046#53231046

Answer (score 6):

The client uses java.util.logging, the easiest way is to use SLF4J.
See [JUL to SLF4J Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117030/jul-to-slf4j-bridge) for more information.

3 steps are required:

1. Add [jul-to-slf4j bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) to you classpath with runtime scope.
   **Maven:**

   ```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

**Gradle**:

```
`runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jul-to-slf4j', version: '1.7.25'`
```

2. Add in logback.xml (logback-test.xml), don't forget to add a STDOUT appender (or change it accordingly)

   ```
   <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
       <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
   </contextListener>

   <logger name="jdk.internal.httpclient.debug" level="debug" additivity="false">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   </logger>

   <root level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
   </root>
   ```
3. Add in your code:

   ```
    static {
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }
   ```

Alternatively, for educational purposes it is possible to add a system property:
`-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=all`
which will enable all logging printing to the console.

Comment: thank you this worked for me, after following ALL steps :)

Comment: Thanks @Maxim for this answer. However, this does log a lot of information. Is there a way to log only httpclient.wire.content.wire logs using this approach?