# Spring Logging setting Log level for JDK classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, java.util.logging, spring-logback

currently I'm trying to set trace logging level for internal JDK classes, especially for the new HttpClient.

When I add to my application.yaml:

```
logging:
 level:
  root: INFO
```

Everything logs in trace.

But when I want to enable trace logging only for JDK packages like:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    jdk.internal.net.http: TRACE
```

Those packages don't start log in trace, the entire app uses root level, which is INFO.
What do I need to solve this problem? Thanks guys.

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215038/how-to-log-request-response-using-java-net-http-httpclient

Comment: jdk.internal.net.http does not exist anymore since Java 11, AFAIK

Comment: HttpClient logging is configured on command line, not via standard logging levels, AFAIK

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 11

Comment: But I see that for example class CookieFilter has package:
package jdk.internal.net.http;

Comment: Indeed, jdk.internal.net.http is a module private package of module jdk.net.http

Comment: It seems to use the new Platform Logging API: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/264