# javafx.WebView not open local site with socket.io

Tags: java, javafx, webview, socket.io, javafx-webengine

I've noticed strange behavior in **javafx.WebView** version **14-ea+4** and up.

If you open https://socketio-chat-h9jt.herokuapp.com/ in **javafx.WebView** of any version, then there will be no problems. The site works well.

But if you install this chat (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) locally on your PC, start the **NodeJs** server and open http://localhost:3000 in **javafx.WebView** version **14-ea+4** and above, then the page will not load and throw an 'Unknown Error' error.

If you use version **14-ea+2** and below, then there will be no error and the page will load.

If you use a proxy before loading the page then the page will open but **socket.io** won't work. For the proxy to work, you need to replace *'localhost'* with an **IPv4** address, which can be found using the *'ipconfig'* command in cmd. In my case *'localhost' -> '192.168.56.1'*:

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://192.168.56.1:3000/");
if (uri.getHost() != null) System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", uri.getHost());
if (uri.getPort() != -1) System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(uri.getPort()));
```

If webkit loggers are enabled, then **com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader** will spam **99** with the error **'HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes'**.

Why did the proxy affect the result so much and what changed in **javafx.WebView** version **14-ea+4** that got such problems?
Why **socket.io chat** from the Internet opens well, but the same **socket.io chat** installed locally does not open?

I need **WebView** **version 18** because I need transparency, so unfortunately I can't use a version lower than this...

**socket.io index.js:**

```
// Setup basic express server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Chatroom

let numUsers = 0;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  let addedUser = false;

  // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
  socket.on('new message', (data) => {
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
  socket.on('add user', (username) => {
    if (addedUser) return;

    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
    ++numUsers;
    addedUser = true;
    socket.emit('login', {
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
    // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
    socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
      username: socket.username,
      numUsers: numUsers
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'typing', we broadcast it to others
  socket.on('typing', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', {
      username: socket.username
    });
  });

  // when the client emits 'stop typing', we broadcast it to others
  socket.on('stop typing', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('stop typing', {
      username: socket.username
    });
  });

  // when the user disconnects.. perform this
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    if (addedUser) {
      --numUsers;

      // echo globally that this client has left
      socket.broadcast.emit('user left', {
        username: socket.username,
        numUsers: numUsers
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Example simple webview app **Main.java**:

```
WebView wv = new WebView();

@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String url = "http://localhost:3000";

        // use proxy
        //String url = "http://192.168.56.1:3000"; // IPv4:3000
        //URI uri = URI.create(url);
        //if (uri.getHost() != null) System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", uri.getHost());
        //if (uri.getPort() != -1) System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", String.valueOf(uri.getPort()));

        wv.getEngine().load(url);
        scene = new Scene(wv, 750, 800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

Comment: The webview http client implementation was [changed in JavaFX 14](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8211308).  There may be an undocumented, unsupported system property to switch webview back to the prior http implementation in some later JavaFX versions.

Comment: Here is the [context switch which may be used to switch the HTTP implementation used by JavaFX](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/pull/14/files#diff-593f23fc8227e40ac4ddaf39568aaa3a3abc8204373f9a64cfe07336074bf761R99): System property: `com.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader`, if true and running on a compatible JDK, it will use the java.net.http client from JavaFX 11+, otherwise it will use the `URLConnection` class which has always been in the JDK.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for the answer, most likely this is the right solution, since it helped another person. I can't replicate my success. Adding a parameter does not solve the problem while trying to figure out why... Using maven, I add "-Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader=false" parameter to the maven application launch configuration in the 'VM options' field in the 'Java Options' section. Is everything right?

Comment: Run it from the command line, e.g. `java -Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader=false <yourmodule>/<yourpackage>.Main`.  I do not know if it would actually address your problem or not.  You can [provide other system properties to the log java net HTTP client calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215038/how-to-log-request-response-using-java-net-http-httpclient).  If useHTTP2Loader is switched off, then you shouldn't see  the java net HTTP client calls being generated for the WebView calls.

Comment: @jewelsea I didn't understand how to use *java -Dcom.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader=false <yourmodule>/<yourpackage>.Main* but I tried *System.setProperty('com.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader', 'false')* and after that, instead of an _'Unknown Error'_ error, it threw a _'Connection refused'_ error. This is already a success. I tried to open my site and... It opened and the sockets worked! You can write a response and complete it with *System.setProperty('com.sun.webkit.useHTTP2Loader'*, 'false'); to make it the best.